# PHP Mailer is giving me error 404

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

Here is my html for my form, action and everything else should be correct, I'm thinking its probably my php?

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Jane Doe">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="formBtn">Send Email</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

---

Here is my PHP that I copied and then changed the details to fit myself from github.

---

```
<?php

require 'phpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'email@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'email@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Bradley';
$mail->addAddress('email@gmail.com', 'Brad');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo('email@gmail.com', 'Reply address');


$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Email from Vote Unanimous';
$mail->Body    = 'You have a new email from your Vote Unanimous account. You should have a name and new email';
$mail->AltBody = 'You have a new email from your Vote Unanimous account. You should have a name and new email';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: Most probably you've wrongly linked your autoload file, put it in the same directory in which your email sending file exists, and modify the `require`;

Comment: Is the copied from github form actually called `index.php` to match the `action="index.php"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping out. I had to change my password in my gmail account to make it work